# Porque se salta el evento timer?

Tags: c#, .net, hilos

Estoy haciendo una práctica con threads, procesos,hilos y delegados con c#, quiero que las etiquetas se vayan moviendo y tengo este código:

```
    public System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmEtq = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    public ClPing(Form xpadre,string xip,int xvel,Color xcolor)
    {
        frmpare = xpare;
        ip = xip;
        velocidad = xvel;
        colorines = xcolor;
        dx = random.Next(10, 21);
        dy = random.Next(10, 21);
        tmEtq.Interval = 100;
        inietiqueta();
        tmEtq.Tick += new EventHandler(TmEtq_Tick);
    }
```

Lo que pasa es cuando hace la función de inietiqueta(), directamente pasa de tmEtq.Tick y se va a hacer otra cosa.

```
    private void TmEtq_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        delegatMoureEtiqueta delegatMoureEtiqueta = new delegatMoureEtiqueta(moveretiqueta);
        if (this.dx > 0 && this.etiqueta.Right >= this.frmpadre.Width)
            this.dx = -this.dx;
        if (this.dx < 0 && this.etiqueta.Left <= 0)
            this.dx = -this.dx;
        if (this.dy > 0 && this.etiqueta.Bottom >= this.frmpadre.Height - 40)
            this.dy = -this.dy;
        if (this.dy < 0 && this.etiqueta.Top <= 0)
            this.dy = -this.dy;

        frmpadre.Invoke(delegatMoureEtiqueta);
       
    }
```

Cual es la explicación de esto? He hecho varias cosas con timer y es la primera vez que me pasa esto.

Comment: Qué significa: _hace la función de inietiqueta(), directamente_ ?  y que haces dentro de esa funcion?

Comment: en inietiqueta simplemente inicializo el label, tamaño, colores, texto... Es solo que al acabar la funcion pasa de tmEtq, pero si quito la función inietiqueta igual. Puede que tenga que ver con los threads?

Comment: podrias poner un console.log, o console.writeline, o console.debug,  despues de inietiqueta(); y ver si entra alli, si entra entonces si es algo de los hilos, si no.. entonces hay alguna exception controlada que esta  pasando en inietiqueta();... es lo que se me ocurre

Comment: Es que he hecho el debug, es lo que digo, que ni entra. Todo lo otro lo hace perfecto, y con el debug inietiqueta no me ha hecho ningun fallo. Pero cuando llega a tmEtq.Tick += new EventHandler(TmEtq_Tick); es que directamente ni entra el debug, pasa de el, no se si me explico.

Comment: al decir que no se ejecuta ese codigo, quieres decir que no se inicia el timer? porque alli solo le estas asignando el delegado al timer... osea no se esta mandando ejecutar, lo que yo te preguntaba es si la instruccion llega a la linea  despues de inietiqueta();, sin importar que linea sea... o como sabes que al timer no se le asigna el tick?